# Trying to install Netflix app

Tags: ps3, netflix

I'm trying to install Netflix on my Playstation 3. I have been through the tutorial on the Netflix site without success. I'm going to "what's new" section and clicking on Netflix (using the X button) but nothing happens.

Is there any way to install it offline? Copying it to an USB stick and installing it from there?

Comment: What sort of issues are you having? Can you be more specific? Have you tried installing it through the icon under the "Video" tab on the PS3's XMB menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange that you have this problem. Might be some issue with PSN. Can you install other applications like Vudu or Hulu+?

Also you can try pointing the PS3 browser to [www.netflix.com](http://www.netflix.com). I think it gives you an option to download it from there.